# How to change upload directory in wp_handle_upload

Tags: php, uploads

I am trying to work out how to use the wp_handle_upload function for a custom plugin so that i can specify my own own upload directory. The code so far takes a file from my plugin settings page and uploads to the folder uploads folder with the year and month.

I came across this link which I thought might have some clues - http://yoast.com/smarter-upload-handling-wp-plugins

```
if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == "post"){

     $overrides = array('test_form' => false);
     $file = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['binaryFile'], $overrides);

     echo "<pre>" . print_r($file, true) . "</pre>";
}
```

**How can I upload to a directory of my choosing?**

Any help much appreciated guys.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a complete example for how we do it in Easy Digital Downloads:

```
/**
 * Set Upload Directory
 *
 * Sets the upload dir to edd. This function is called from
 * edd_change_downloads_upload_dir()
 *
 * @since 1.0
 * @return array Upload directory information
*/
function edd_set_upload_dir( $upload ) {
    $upload['subdir'] = '/edd' . $upload['subdir'];
    $upload['path'] = $upload['basedir'] . $upload['subdir'];
    $upload['url']  = $upload['baseurl'] . $upload['subdir'];
    return $upload;
}


/**
 * Change Downloads Upload Directory
 *
 * Hooks the edd_set_upload_dir filter when appropriate. This function works by
 * hooking on the WordPress Media Uploader and moving the uploading files that
 * are used for EDD to an edd directory under wp-content/uploads/ therefore,
 * the new directory is wp-content/uploads/edd/{year}/{month}. This directory
 * provides protection to anything uploaded to it.
 *
 * @since 1.0
 * @global $pagenow
 * @return void
 */
function edd_change_downloads_upload_dir() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) && ( 'async-upload.php' == $pagenow || 'media-upload.php' == $pagenow ) ) {
        if ( 'download' == get_post_type( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ) {
            add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'edd_set_upload_dir' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'edd_change_downloads_upload_dir', 999 );
```

Comment: Note, we only modify the upload directory when uploading files from our Downloads custom post type page. You will need to adjust it for your plugin's settings page.

Comment: It lacks "]" with `$upload['url'`

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember doing exactly this in practice, but most (all?) upload path handling goes through [`wp_upload_dir()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_upload_dir/) that applies `upload_dir` filter to returned information. You should try filtering it for the duration of your code running and adjusting paths to wanted location.

Comment: This method is easy to implement. An example can be found at this link, (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_dir)[https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_dir].